# CSS padding ignored

Tags: html, css

I have a nav bar, and would like to set a default padding on each tab as being 14px wide, however for the first tab, which I will use as my logo, I wish to have a padding 18px wide. However when I tried to implement this, it did not work, and continued to use the 14px default.

```css
#nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

#nav>li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#nav>li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#logo {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 18px 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="/home" id="logo">Logo</a></li>
  <li><a href="/opt1">Opt1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/opt2">Opt2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/opt3">Opt3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `#logo` to `#nav > li a#logo`

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with CSS specificity

Instead of `#logo`, use `nav > li a#logo`

When you want to override a style, you need a **more** specific selector

Answer (score 1):

It's because of CSS specificity: `#nav > li a` has a higher specificity then just `#logo`. This is why @Bouh's answer works. I would read up on it.

Here's a specificity calculator: https://specificity.keegan.st/

Alternatively, you can avoid specificity issues by avoiding overuse of ids and child selectors, for example:

```css
.navlist {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

.navlist-item {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navlink {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 18px 16px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navlist" id="nav">
  <li class="navlist-item"><a class="navlink logo" href="/home" id="logo">Logo</a></li>
  <li class="navlist-item"><a class="navlink" href="/opt1">Opt1</a></li>
  <li class="navlist-item"><a class="navlink" href="/opt2">Opt2</a></li>
  <li class="navlist-item"><a class="navlink" href="/opt3">Opt3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is CSS selector specificity.

```css
#nav > li a
```

is more specific than:

```css
#logo
```

so the first example here will always win for the HTML you've provided (regardless of order in the CSS file)

Here is an updated set of CSS rules:

```css
#nav {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

#nav > li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#nav > li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

##nav > li a#logo { /* this selector has been changed to be more specific */
    background-color: green;
    padding: 18px 16px;
}
```